# files and folder read only attribute problem in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Im running windows 7 home premium and my issue is when i remove read only attribute from a folder it again check on readonly.

```
C:\Program Files\EasyPHP1-8\www\bagsdefined
```

i want to remove readony check from bagsdefined folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the files you want to manipulate into
`C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\..` instead of `C:\Program Files\..` and you may have R/W access. replace `XXXXX` with the username.

The same applies for files within
`C:\Program Files (x86)\..`  ==>  `C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)`

It is part of Microsoft UAC Virtualization scheme in Win7. From within any program the files will appear within their original location in Program Files, but in fact they are not. It is kinda spooky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 7 to test but Windows Explorer doesn't recognise the read-only attribute of *folders*.

Answer (score 0):

The folder (and files) are not read only - they are protected by UAC. Any program that wants to write to them must be running as administrator (this is different from you being signed in as administrator.) Since that's annoying, I recommend you move the files somewhere else. AppData is the recommended location for files the user doesn't use outside the program. Something under MyDocuments, or a folder you ask the user to choose, is the recommended location for files the user will want to get to with Windows Explorer.